# For loop and matrix indexing in matlab ques

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix-indexing

I have defined a matrix (initial_matrix) equal to 0 by using a for loop as:

```
I = 5;   % e.g number of nodes
for i =1:I
    initial_matrix = [0];    // an initial matrix will be generated for each node
end
```

Now, for each node i, I will consider all other nodes but not the node i itself and subtract each of them from 1 and take their product:

for node 1:

```
result = (1 - initial_matrix of node 2) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 3) * ...
    (1 - initial_matrix of node 4) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 5)
```

for node 2:

```
result = (1 - initial_matrix of node 1) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 3) * ...
    (1 - initial_matrix of node 4) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 5)
```

for node 3:

```
result = (1 - initial_matrix of node 1) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 2) * ...
    (1 - initial_matrix of node 4) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 5)
```

and so..for the remaining 2 nodes!

Can any one tell me or give me hints on how this can be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Dan. The above example was for the case when node 1 is considered. Now if I consider node 2: then i should get: result = (1 - initial_matrix of node 1) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 3) * ...
    (1 - initial_matrix of node 4) * (1 - initial_matrix of node 5) ....similarly for node 3 etc

Comment: This is not an example. If the answers below aren't what you're looking for, you should ADD TO YOUR QUESTION (i.e. not a comment) a numerical small worked example

Comment: Do you really want the matrix product, or the elementwise product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each product (per node) you need to have all initial matrices in advance, so you should modify your initial loop to something along these lines:

```
initial_matrix = cell(I, 1);
for i = 1:I
    initial_matrix{i} = blah blah... %// Generated for each node
end
```

Then you can add another nested loop that does something like the following:

```
result = cell(I, 1);
for k = 1:I

    %// Compute product
    result{k} = 1;
    for n = setdiff(1:I, k)
        result{k} = result{k} * (1 - initial_matrix{n});
    end
end
```

Comment: @ Eitan T, but this wont run for node 2 and so on..coz for node 1 i will consider 2,3,4 and 5, then for node 2: 1,3,4 and 5, for node 3: 1,2,4 and 5....and so on....

Comment: So for each node you want to consider all nodes but itself? Please take the time to add this missing information to the question.

Comment: yes, i want to consider all the nodes expect the node in question!

Comment: Especially when you set it to zero, you will want to do: `prod(1-initial, 3)` -- This applied to your previous version, I can look at the udated one later.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin You can't use `prod` and `cumprod` because they do element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication...

Comment: @EitanT: Ok. I am checking the code

Comment: @user2762192 Please use the update code that employs cell arrays :)

Comment: @EitanT, i get the following error: Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in colll (line 14)
    result{k} = eye(size(result{k}));

Comment: @user2762192 You're right, forgot to updated that. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the steps you need to take:

Assuming all matrices are of the same size and that you want to do elementwise multiplication:

1. Concatenate all of them into one big matrix `initialMatrices`, as [desribed here.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/75954)
2. Apply `cumprod` on `1-initialMatrices`
3. If you used `cumprod` Extract the matrices that you need from this result

Some things to pay attention to:

- Maybe preprocess the first initial matrix by doing one minus it, or remove it.
- Make sure you build the total matrix in the right 'direction'. Check `help cumprod` for what the right direction is.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are not creating an initial matrix for each node. If you want to have a separate one for each, I would suggest you to define a structure. So you will have:

```
I = 5;
for i =1:I
    initial_matrix.(sprintf('Node%d',i)) = [0];    % an initial matrix will be generated for each node
end
```

Then you can maybe do something like the following to do your operation (if I understood it right):

```
    for i =1:I
        numnode=[1:I]
        numnode(numnode==i)=[]
        for ind = 1:numel(numnode)-1
            NewMatrix.(sprintf('Node%d',i)) = (1- initial_matrix.sprintf('Node%d',numnode(ind))))*(1- initial_matrix.(sprintf('Node%d',numnode(ind+1))))
            end
    end
```

You can verify if this is correct by using a `rand(1)` statement instead of `[0]` while defining the initial_matrix.

I hope I understood you correctly

Comment: But where's the part that does multiplication?

Comment: @Eitan just realized my mistake and modified it. Should be multiplying now.

Comment: One more thing: while it certainly works, it seems to me that using structs and dynamic referencing is an unnecessary over-complication. Using cell arrays here definitely would be much cleaner.